# How to make a simple event calendar in a c# MVC web project

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, calendar

I'm making a web page that has a calendar in it. It will be used as an event calendar, but I need the events info to come from a database, not hard coded. I also need it so it only displays the events (you can not add one) but when clicked it takes you to another web page (that will add it to the database). I need it this way because of user control. Only the user who creates the event should be able to delete or edit it(which is why I want it to go to another page).

I've been googleing like crazy but have not found anything I need. I did find a calendar called FullCalendar but I can't figure any way to get the events into it. They require an array of events but of course I can't use a server side variable like @Model.events or anything in the javascript. I also can't find one that doesn't allow everyone to edit or delete others posts (which is a security issue).

I'm not familiar with javascript so I have no idea how to get a variable form my database into the script.

Please help. I just want a very simple calendar that shows events that I can get from my own database. Hopefully one that allows hyperlinks as the events name so I can have it go to the events own page when clicked.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's difficult to answer your question (as you have not provided any code as to what you have tried or researched so far), if you are looking for something simple, I would recommend looking at creating a web helper for your calendar. By doing this, you can do everything you are looking to do without having to use JavaScript. A starting (but very simple) example of a calendar web helper is found here: [ASP.NET MVC Calendar Helper](http://www.antiyes.com/aspnet-mvc-calendar-helper)

However, might I also recommend that you spend some time learning JavaScript as there is quite a bit you can do to improve the user experience. But, as the previous example shows, you don't necessarily have to.

Comment: thank you. That works great. I was able to insert links to the other pages and everything from the database using that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you need some kind of a calendar where a user can manage his tasks. I can advise you a calendar that requires no knowledge of JavaScript, stores info to a database, and you can adjust access rights to your calendar (so if you need, only one user can make changes to it). It is described in this [tutorial](http://scheduler-net.com/docs/tutorialstask_manager.html), and you can also check the [demo](http://scheduler-net.com/demo.aspx). To my mind, it should be a good solution for you.